# What is IIdentity.Name expected to return?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to populate a `ClaimsIdentity` object in ASP.NET Core based on user session data coming from a remote service. I've noticed that in some cases (e.g. antiforgery system) ASP.NET Core expects `IIdentity.Name` to be populated. However, I'm not sure what exactly to populate it with and how the information is used by the framework (if at all).

For example, we could use:

- username (but some users log in with SSO and don't have this)
- firstname + lastname (not unique)
- user ID
- session ID (varies by session)
- something else

What does ASP.NET Core (or .NET in general since `IIdentity` is a general .NET Concept) expect this property to represent?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that [`IIdentity.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iidentity.name?view=net-7.0) documentation is pretty clear:

> The name of the user on whose behalf the code is running.

So in your case this should be firstname + lastname and uniqueness should not be a concern (because it would be a quite odd expectation from framework to have a guarantee of names uniqueness)

Also note the following remark:

> Name is typically set to an empty string ("") for an unauthenticated entity, but can take other values.

This can be a reason why it is also included in stuff like antiforgery token.

Also from [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

> The client's username is already embedded in the generated tokens, so there's no need to include this information.

Comment: If name is non-unique, why would it be included in the anti-forgery token?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion maybe my answer is wrong - you can dive into [`DefaultAntiforgeryTokenGenerator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fd211fb22e07f8b03e72d64b50117ba5d4ddf9a4/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultAntiforgeryTokenGenerator.cs#L11) implementation and check why it tries to use name. My guess would be that [`DefaultClaimUidExtractor.ExtractClaimUid`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fd211fb22e07f8b03e72d64b50117ba5d4ddf9a4/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultClaimUidExtractor.cs) fails to extract needed data.